Arduino keeps restarting with L9110 and DC motor
I am trying to control a DC motor using the L9110 motor driver and Arduino MEGA 2560.
Here's the code.
#include <Arduino.h>

const int rightA = A3;
const int rightB = A2;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(rightA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rightB, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("tick");

  digitalWrite(rightA, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rightB, LOW);
  Serial.println("waiting for 1s...\n");

  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("stopping");
  digitalWrite(rightA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(rightB, LOW);
  
  Serial.println("waiting for 5s...\n");
  delay(5000);
}


So it should spin the motor for 1s, then wait for 5s and repeat. This only happens once or twice and then Arduino either freezes or restarts and the motor stays on.

I use a separate power supply for the driver board, connected GND of Arduino and the driver, and also have a 100nF capacitor connected. These are the first most obvious issues I found on other forums, so this shouldn't be a problem.
The external power adapter is 5V 1A, and the motor current draw shouldn't exceed 500mA. Yet, it still doesn't work. Could anyone point me in the right direction as to where to look?

I use these motors

The startup motor current is likely many times that of a running motor. As soon as the motor exceed the power capacity of the supply, the supply voltage will likely drop. After dropping lower than either Arduino pin A1 or A2, the motor will try to pull current from the Arduino I/O pins. That could cause a number of problems. Some of which include trying to pull power from the Macbook USB port.
When choosing a power supply, many choose double the highest expected current. Motors are difficult to deal with because the more work they do the more current they can pull.
If you are constrained to a 5V/1A power supply consider solving this problem in software. Consider using a PWM signal to "gently start" the electric motor.
Or obtain a power supply rated at many more Amps to cover the motor startup current draw.

Thanks for the insights. I eventually fixed it by using TB6612FNG driver with MOSFETs and also use PWM to start the motors gently.

Your 5V 1A power adapter may not provide enough current for the motor and driver board. Motors can draw more current during startup or under load. Try a power supply with a higher current rating, such as 5V 2A or more. Measure the voltage across the motor driver's Vcc and GND pins when the motor is running. If the voltage drops significantly below 5V, the power supply is insufficient. Add a 10µF or 100µF electrolytic capacitor in parallel with the 100nF ceramic capacitor for better signal smoothing. You may also want to make an L9110 module by yourself:
https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/DIY_Motor_Control_Building_and_Using_the_L9110_Module_679076e3.html

hey thanks for you answer, I eventually resolved it by replacing the L9110 module with TB6612FNG
